# Searching and Counting Greatest Values

Tags: java

I was given the following problem:

Write a Java program that prompts  the user to enter 10 positive integers and then Find the biggest value and number of its occurrences.  Hint: use a While Loop.

> Sample Run: please enter 10 numbers:
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> 46
>
> 1
>
> 0
>
> 5
>
> 46
>
> 46
>
> 6
>
> 27
>
> The biggest value is:  46  and It occurs  3 times.
>
> ---

Below is my solution:

```
     import java.util.*;
      public class numbers{


       public static void main(String args[]){;
          Scanner input=new Scanner (System.in);


            int n=0;
             int H=1;
            int y=0;
        System.out.println("please Enter 10 numbers:");
         while (n<10){
          int f=input.nextInt();

             if ( f>n)
              y=f;

           else if(y==f)
               H++;}

     System.out.println("the biggest value is: "+
                        n+" and it is occurs "+
                        H+" times");
      }}
```

but the problem the result is not correct :"(

what should i do ?!

---

thanks but it makes Infinite loop!!

```
      import java.util.*;
      public class numbers{


     public static void main(String args[]){;
      Scanner input=new Scanner (System.in);


      int n=0;
      int H=0;
      int y=0;
       System.out.println("please Enter 10 numbers:");
        while (n<10){
        int f=input.nextInt();

         if ( f>y){
         y=f;
         H=1;}
       else if(y==f){
          H++;
          n++; }
             }
        System.out.println("the biggest value is: "+y+" and it is occurs "+H+" times");
           }}
```

finally I found my mistakes " thanks for help"

after correcting my code

```
       import java.util.*;
       public class numbers{
       //main method

         public static void main(String args[]){;
         Scanner input=new Scanner (System.in);


         int n=0;
         int H=0;
         int y=0;
        System.out.println("please Enter 10 numbers:");
        while (n<10){
        int f=input.nextInt();//f the numbers

        if(y==f)
       H++;//to count how many repeat


        if ( f>y){
      y=f;// if numbers greater than y put value of f in y 

       H=1;}
       n++;//to update counter
         }
       System.out.println("the biggest value is: "+y+" and it is occurs "+H+" times");
       }// end main
       }// end class
```

Comment: How is it not correct? What's not working? And what's that title?

Comment: I think something has happened to your title

Comment: your while loop is flawed. you don't reset the `H++` counter when switching numbers, so you're simply counting ALL duplicate numbers. e.g. `1 2 2 4 4 9` will output 4, because there's 4 individual numbers that have duplicates.

Comment: You should learn how to use a debugger, and step through your code until you find the error.

Comment: momcen ahad yhal? wtf is that?

Comment: momcen ahad yhal?<< it is means can anyone correct the code >>it is arabic language :)

Comment: @hanooee In Arabic, there is a different alphabet,  so the translation of 'Can anyone correct the code?' is along the lines of 'يمكن لأي شخص أن يصحح الرمز؟'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First error:

`System.out.println("the biggest value is: "+n+" and it is occurs "+H+" times");}}`

The `n` is your TryCount. Should be:

`System.out.println("the biggest value is: "+y+" and it is occurs "+H+" times");}}`

Second error:

You are increasing the count of the "highest" number: `else if(y==f) H++;` - but you are NOT taking into account, what should happen, when that changes? So, entering 1,1,1,1,1,1,2, will give you "7 occurences of 2" - thats wrong.

You need to "reset" (Set to "1") the "Highest-Occurence-Count", when a new Highest number is recorded:

```
if ( f>y){
   y=f;
   H = 1;
}
```

Third error: Already fixed above: It should be `f>y` not `f>H`

Hint: give your variables **meaningfull** names - so you dont mess up that easy:

```
import java.util.*;
public class numbers{

  public static void main(String args[]){;
    Scanner input=new Scanner (System.in);

    int runs=0;
    int highestCount=0;
    int highestValue=0;

    System.out.println("please Enter 10 numbers:");
    while (runs<10){
      int inputValue=input.nextInt();

      if ( inputValue>highestValue){
        highestValue=inputValue;
        highestCount = 1;
      }

      else if(inputValue==highestValue){
        highestCount++;
      }
    }
    System.out.println("the biggest value is: "+highestValue+" and it is occurs "+highestCount+" times");
  }
}
```

much easier to read, isn't it?